Intermittent Dashboard Loading and Bookmark Toggle Issues in NextJS with Supabase
I'm working on a note storing app using NextJS (pages router), Supabase, and Supabase Auth for user sessions. I encounter two main issues:
Dashboard Loading Issue: When loading localhost:3000/dashboard in development mode, the dashboard often gets stuck on initial load or after a browser refresh. It requires multiple refreshes to load correctly.
Bookmark Toggle Issue: After switching tabs and returning to the app, the bookmark toggle and delete functions stop working. The API call (200 GET) is made, but the state doesn't update. However, other functions like edit/save continue to work after tab switching.
Some console.log info:
Toggling off a bookmark:
dashboard:228 toggling
dashboard:234 Unbookmarking: a55d1b68-1584-4945-b59b-91dc397ac066
dashboard:255 Updated isBookmarked: false
dashboard:228 toggling
dashboard:238 Bookmarking: a5c0be14-01a2-4a88-bc3e-b4e71433a17b
dashboard:255 Updated isBookmarked: true
Switching tabs then returning to app tab:
This loads on tab return:
_app:25 User created or logged in: {message: 'User already exists, proceed to login.'}
dashboard:108 Raw fetched data: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Trying bookmark toggle doesn't work:
dashboard:228 toggling (1st click just this occurs)
dashboard:228 toggling (additional clicks stuck on isBookmarked: true)
dashboard:234 Unbookmarking: 3aa783a4-edef-41a2-8942-145de7643544
dashboard:255 Updated isBookmarked: true
dashboard:228 toggling
dashboard:234 Unbookmarking: 3aa783a4-edef-41a2-8942-145de7643544
dashboard:255 Updated isBookmarked: true
Here is some of the code:
export default function Dashboard() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  console.log("Current theme:", theme);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      router.replace(window.location.pathname);
    }
  }, [router]);

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loadingUser, setLoadingUser] = useState(true);
  const [loadingPrompts, setLoadingPrompts] = useState(true);
  const [loadingBookmarks, setLoadingBookmarks] = useState(true);
  const [savedPrompts, setSavedPrompts] = useState([]);
  const [bookmarkedPrompts, setBookmarkedPrompts] = useState([]);
  const [isBookmarked, setIsBookmarked] = useState(false);
  const [currentPrompt, setCurrentPrompt] = useState(null);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isFormOpen, setIsFormOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isRequestActive, setIsRequestActive] = useState(false);
  const [activeTags, setActiveTags] = useState([]);
  const [selectedPrompt, setSelectedPrompt] = useState(null);
  const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState('');
  const [bookmarkId, setBookmarkId] = useState(null);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editedPromptText, setEditedPromptText] = useState('');

  const toggleFormModal = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsFormOpen(!isFormOpen);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      try {
        const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
        if (user) {
          setUser(user);
          try {
            await syncPrompts();
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error syncing prompts:', error);
          }
          fetchPrompts(user.id);
          fetchBookmarkedPrompts(user.id);
        } else {
          router.push('/auth/sign-in');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting user:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoadingUser(false);
      }
    };

    getUser();

    const { data: { subscription } } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
        router.push('/auth/sign-in');
      } else if (session) {
        setUser(session.user);
        await syncPrompts();
        //fetchPrompts(session.user.id);
        //fetchBookmarkedPrompts(session.user.id);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      if (subscription) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  }, [router]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Selected Prompt Updated:', selectedPrompt);
  }, [selectedPrompt]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Selected Prompt for Display:', selectedPrompt?.full_text);
  }, [selectedPrompt?.full_text]);

  const fetchPrompts = async (userId) => {
    setLoadingPrompts(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/fetchPrompts?userId=${userId}&_cb=${Date.now()}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      console.log("Raw fetched data:", data);
      setSavedPrompts(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching prompts:', error);
      setSavedPrompts([]);
    } finally {
      setLoadingPrompts(false);
    }
  };

  const fetchBookmarkedPrompts = async (userId) => {
    setLoadingBookmarks(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/fetchBookmarkedPrompts?userId=${userId}`, {
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      setBookmarkedPrompts(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching bookmarked prompts:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoadingBookmarks(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSavePrompt = async (promptDetails) => {
    try {
      const tagsString = Array.isArray(promptDetails.tags) ? promptDetails.tags.join(', ') : promptDetails.tags || '';
      const tagsArray = tagsString.split(',').map(tag => tag.trim());

      const promptData = {
        title: promptDetails.title,
        description: promptDetails.description,
        full_text: promptDetails.fullText,
        tags: tagsArray,
        use_cases: promptDetails.useCases || null,
        additional_info: promptDetails.additionalInfo || null,
        user_id: user.id
      };

      console.log("Attempting to insert prompt:", promptData);

      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('user_prompts')
        .insert([promptData])
        .select();

      if (error) {
        console.error("Error inserting prompt:", error);
        throw error;
      }

      console.log("Inserted data:", data);

      if (data && data.length > 0) {
        setSavedPrompts(prevPrompts => [...prevPrompts, data[0]]);
      } else {
        console.error('No data returned after insert operation.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving prompt:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleBookmarkPrompt = async (prompt, type) => {
    if (isRequestActive) return;  // Prevent new requests if one is already in progress
    setIsRequestActive(true);  // Set the request as active

    try {
      const { data: existingBookmarks, error: checkError } = await supabase
        .from('bookmarked_prompts')
        .select('*')
        .eq('user_id', user.id)
        .eq('prompt_id', prompt.id);

      if (checkError) throw checkError;

      if (existingBookmarks && existingBookmarks.length > 0) {
        console.log('Prompt already bookmarked');
      } else {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('bookmarked_prompts')
          .insert([{ user_id: user.id, prompt_id: prompt.id, prompt_type: type }])
          .select('*');

        if (error) throw error;
        setBookmarkedPrompts([...bookmarkedPrompts, data[0]]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error bookmarking prompt:', error);
    } finally {
      setIsRequestActive(false);  // Reset the request state
    }
  };

  const handleUnbookmarkPrompt = async (bookmarkId) => {
    if (isRequestActive) return;
    setIsRequestActive(true);

    try {
      const { error } = await supabase
        .from('bookmarked_prompts')
        .delete()
        .eq('id', bookmarkId);

      if (error) throw error;
      setBookmarkedPrompts(bookmarkedPrompts.filter(bookmark => bookmark.id !== bookmarkId));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error unbookmarking prompt:', error);
    } finally {
      setIsRequestActive(false);
    }
  };

  const handleToggleBookmarkPrompt = async (prompt) => {
    console.log('toggling');
    if (!prompt) return; // Guard clause if prompt is undefined or null

    const bookmark = bookmarkedPrompts.find(b => b.prompt_id === prompt.id);
    if (bookmark) {
      await handleUnbookmarkPrompt(bookmark.id);
      console.log('Unbookmarking:', bookmark.id);
    } else {
      const type = savedPrompts.some(p => p.id === prompt.id && p.user_id === prompt.user_id) ? 'user' : 'system';
      await handleBookmarkPrompt(prompt, type);
      console.log('Bookmarking:', prompt.id);
    }

    // Fetch the updated bookmarks to ensure the state is correctly reflected
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/fetchBookmarkedPrompts?userId=${user.id}`, {
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      const bookmarksData = await response.json();
      setBookmarkedPrompts(bookmarksData);

      const isNowBookmarked = bookmarksData.some(b => b.prompt_id === prompt.id);
      console.log('Updated isBookmarked:', isNowBookmarked);
      setIsBookmarked(isNowBookmarked); // Ensure the state is correctly updated
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching updated bookmarks:', error);
    }
  };


  const handleRemovePrompt = async (promptId) => {
    try {
      const { error } = await supabase
        .from('user_prompts')
        .delete()
        .eq('id', promptId);

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        setSavedPrompts(savedPrompts.filter(prompt => prompt.id !== promptId));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error removing prompt:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    setSelectedPrompt(null);
    setCopySuccess(''); // Resets the copy success message
  };

  const handleDeletePrompt = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent triggering other click events

    // Check if the prompt is bookmarked and remove the bookmark
    const bookmark = bookmarkedPrompts.find(b => b.prompt_id === selectedPrompt.id);

    handleUnbookmarkPrompt(bookmark.id)
    // if (bookmark) {
    //   handleUnbookmarkPrompt(bookmark.id);
    // }

    handleRemovePrompt(selectedPrompt.id);
    handleCloseModal(); // Close modal after deleting
  };

  const handleSelectPrompt = (promptId) => {
    if (currentPrompt && currentPrompt.id === promptId) {
      // Reset currentPrompt to force re-render
      setCurrentPrompt(null);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCurrentPrompt(savedPrompts.find(p => p.id === promptId));
      }, 0);
    } else {
      setCurrentPrompt(savedPrompts.find(p => p.id === promptId));
    }
  };

  const handleSaveEditedPrompt = async () => {
    console.log("Attempting to update:", selectedPrompt.id, editedPromptText);
    const updatedPromptData = {
      id: selectedPrompt.id,
      fullText: editedPromptText,
      userId: selectedPrompt.user_id
    };

    try {
      console.log("Sending update to server:", updatedPromptData);
      const response = await fetch('/api/updatePrompt', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedPromptData)
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const result = await response.json();  // This will have the updated prompt data from the server
      console.log("Update successful, received from server:", result);

      // Verify what's currently in savedPrompts before update
      console.log("Current savedPrompts before update:", savedPrompts);

      // Update the prompts list with the updated prompt from the backend
      const newSavedPrompts = savedPrompts.map(prompt =>
        prompt.id === selectedPrompt.id ? { ...prompt, ...result } : prompt
      );
      console.log("New savedPrompts after update:", newSavedPrompts);
      setSavedPrompts(newSavedPrompts);

      // Also update the selectedPrompt to reflect the new data
      console.log("Updating selectedPrompt with new data:", { ...selectedPrompt, ...result });
      setSelectedPrompt({ ...selectedPrompt, ...result });

      setIsEditing(false);
      setEditedPromptText('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to save prompt:", error);
    }
  };

Some user-related code:
// pages/api/createUser.js
import { supabase } from '../../lib/supabaseClient';  // Ensure the path is correct

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
        return res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method Not Allowed' });
    }

    const { user } = req.body;

    // Validate the input
    if (!user || !user.id || !user.email) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid user data' });
    }

    try {
        console.log(`Checking if user exists: ${user.id}`);
        
        // Check if the user already exists in your custom 'users' table
        const { data: existingUser, error: existingUserError } = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .select('*')
            .eq('id', user.id)
            .single();

        if (existingUserError) {
            if (existingUserError.code === 'PGRST116') { // Handle specific Supabase error codes if needed
                // User not found, proceed to insert
                console.log(`User not found, will proceed to insert: ${user.id}`);
            } else {
                console.error("Error fetching user:", existingUserError.message);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching user: ' + existingUserError.message });
            }
        }

        if (existingUser) {
            console.log(`User already exists: ${user.id}`);
            // User already exists, so just confirm the login and proceed without insertion
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User already exists, proceed to login.' });
        }

        // Proceed to insert the new user if not existing
        console.log(`Inserting new user: ${user.id}`);
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .insert([
                { id: user.id, email: user.email }  // Assuming 'id' comes from auth.users
            ]);

        if (error) {
            console.error("Error inserting data:", error.message);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error inserting data: ' + error.message });
        }

        console.log(`User inserted successfully: ${user.id}`);
        return res.status(200).json(data);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Unexpected error:", error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unexpected error: ' + error.message });
    }
}

// pages/_app.js
import '../app/globals.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { supabase } from '../lib/supabaseClient';
import { ThemeProvider } from '../context/themeContext';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { data: listener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
        const user = session.user;
        try {
          const response = await fetch('/api/createUser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
          });

          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
          }

          const result = await response.json();
          console.log('User created or logged in:', result);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error creating user:', error);
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      listener.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

// hooks/useSyncUser.js nextjs
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { supabase } from '../lib/supabaseClient';

function useSyncUser() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { data: listener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
        const user = session.user;
        await fetch('/api/createUser', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
        });
      }
    });

    return () => {
      listener.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
}

export default useSyncUser;

Tried a bunch of console logging, different browsers, code variations, not sure. Any suggestions on debugging or potential fixes would be greatly appreciated.
